# How to display modal elements from an element displayed in full screen using the requestFullscreen() method?

Tags: javascript, html, css

We use the Element.requestFullscreen() method to display an element in full screen. In this element, we have inserted clickable buttons that open dialog boxes. But these dialog boxes only open below the parent element which is in requestFullscreen(). How to show the modal in front of the fullscreen element?

Comment: It sounds like the modal is not a child of the full screen element.

Comment: the modal is inside the fullscreen element in html

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution we needed

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14923

cdk material provide overlay cdk with fullscreen support